# Stacking and counting rectangles in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, gis

I have over one million overlapping 2D rectangles (not rotated) that I want to stack together and count to form a heatmap/density map/2D Histogram showing which areas have more rectangles and which areas have less. Ideally I'd like to do this in Python. Conceptually this is a very simple problem but I'm not sure how to do the stacking calculation efficiently.

**Optimisation possibility**

The coordinates are stored in a database. I can thus simply `GROUP BY` the coordinates to get it down to ~300,000^ rectangles each of which has a single value indicating how many rectangles it represents. The problem then slightly changes to one of stacking the rectangles and summing their values (not counting). *(^ I can probably get this number a lot lower, but that's beyond the scope of this question)*

**Data**

Rectangles, defined as simple bottom-left top-right coordinate pairs.

```
[[0, 0], [300, 400]]
[[10, 30], [50, 35]]
[[243, 12], [244, 13]]
...
```

**Options**

I've considered several options but none seem good as they're using GIS tools to solve a not-necessarily GIS problem:

1. *Shapely library* - it's not really designed for this as I'm simply stacking/counting things.
2. *GDAL* via [gdalcalc](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#gdal-calc)-  - especially for summing the values but that then introduces a lot of extra work for creating/managing several hundred thousand rasters in the first place (even virtual ones).
3. Something with *Numpy*/*Pandas* or similar? I've never used these libraries before but googling around for this problem they come up a lot although never in a way that looked applicable.
4. Convert the rectangles to grids of 1D points and simply feed them into `2dhist`. Very inefficient.

So, what's an efficient way to convert lots of overlapping rectangles into a density map?

Comment: Maybe you can just plot the rectangles with small alpha value, if you somehow know how many of them would be able to stack (not to exceed 1)? Overlapping such rectangles would result in such heat map (although monochromatic). Matplotlib has function to plot rectangles (matplotlib.patches.Rectangle)

Comment: @ErnestPokropek - thanks for the suggestion. That did occur to me but I didn't investigate it. Nice to know Matplotlib can do it, but I think a million rectangles will probably be too many for this mechanism unless the alpha value is miniscule.

Comment: Exactly but Ernest's solution is valid. It is the problem being difficult by itself. With millions of rectangles, a heatmap will hardly be feasible because you have a tradeoff between sensitiveness of the representation for small ranges (this difference would barely show) and total scale range. Might consider making several heatmaps and/or changing some classification.

Comment: @Attersson - excellent points. I know Ernest's solution is valid, but I'm hoping for something more numerical in nature. That way I'll have more control over the representation because as you note, for this many values it's going to require some tweaking to get anything meaningful. I didn't raise it in the question because that in the easy-to-solve (if possibly time consuming) category :-) .

Comment: Maybe you can look up some geography-related plotting libraries? They usually work on coordinates, which are numerical values as well, and your rectangles are some sort of regions.

Comment: I would use something *similar* to a zbuffer but where the z value contains the overlaps. Then just loop over each rectangle increasing the z value by its sorted sum for each pixel it occupies. Once you've gone through them all you can query each pixel for the "number of overlap" value, and display as appropriate.

Comment: @ErnestPokropek - You're closer than you think. The rectangles *are* spatial extents and I could manually solve this problem with GIS tools but I need something repeatable and automated, hence Python. I hoped approaching it as more of a math-ish problem would produce a better solution.

Comment: I meant that you should perhaps treat the data like location one and use python libraries for plotting such thing. I've found such example using GeoPandas, it might help you
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/perrygeo/c426355e40037c452434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with numpy. Yeah, it's ugly, but it does the job.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[[0, 0], [300, 400]],
        [[10, 30], [50, 35]],
        [[143, 12], [244, 113]]]    # I modified this for better visualization
values = [1, 3, 4]    # if your rectangles have values

data_range = [1000, 1000]    # assumed max data range is (0, 999)
areas = np.zeros(data_range)    # initialize empty area
for i, points in enumerate(data):
    areas[points[0][1]:points[1][1]+1, points[0][0]:points[1][0]+1] += values[i]    # I agree that it's too ugly
    # I use `+1` to take these points too
    # change `values[i]` to `1` if it just needs counting

# visualize result
plt.imshow(areas)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

result:
[image].

Comment: Thanks - this exactly does it and extremely quickly too; on the order of a few seconds for the entire dataset! I did have to add a `areas = np.flip(areas, axis=0)` before plotting to switch the y axis around as it's top-left based on numpy and the data is bottom-left based.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan thanks for correcting me. I was initially using `maps` but later forgot to rename it.